# appending contents to a div using Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Javascript code for decryption, now i want to display the decryption string inside a div. I have tried using the following code.

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<script>
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("dsfsdffd", "dsfsdf");
    var dec = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = dec;
</script>

<div id="display1"></div>
```

But the above code not working. What i have done wrong. Is there any solution.

Comment: your `dec ` is `empty string`. Try this `document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = "abc";//dec;` and you will see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your script is executed before the div is added to DOM.
Move your script below the div, best before `</body>` tag.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you then check the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged the question with jQuery, here is the jQuery solution

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("dsfsdffd", "dsfsdf");
   var dec = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
   $("#display1").html(dec);
 });
```

Here you can place your script before the elements.